# Is there a word cloud for applications?

Tags: conky

Is there a script or a software which takes the names of the applications that are open and outputs them on the desktop like a word cloud? Conky implementations are also welcome.

Comment: This is fairly easy as far as finding out which apps are open. Ubuntu's default desktop, Unity, has tools for finding a list of open applications. I have never used conky, however. Do you want me to post the application finding part or do you want complete application that outputs to conky ?

Comment: @Serg Application finding part is fine. I was imagining something that would persistently be there on the desktop, driving you to click on it, in a productivity-increasing kind of way.